# Share step declarations between multiple feature files in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow

I am looking for a way to textually share multiple step declarations between multiple SpecFlow feature files without duplicating them in each feature file.

I have a system that depends on the existence of external data. In my system I have multiple features, that might or might not use that data, so in my tests I am looking for a way to set this up in a shared way, but I would like to have this setup show up in my generated test reports too, and that's where I can't find a good solution.

Given a background as follows:

```
Background:
    Given a category 'A' exists
    And a category 'B' exists
```

Imagine I have two features that depend on the existence of those categories, and a third features that does not. Since each feature contains different scenarios, they are split into separate `.feature` files.

To share the background, I have so far found two possible solutions:

- Do the background setup in a `BeforeScenario` or `BeforeFeature` method. This has a major downside, in that my generated report doesn't contain any information about what has been set up as part of the background. Since I use those reports to communicate with the business department, I force them to make assumptions that those categories exist.
- Duplicate the background text in each feature file. I can create a single binding steps class for step definitions, so that the implementation at least is not duplicated, but that means that I have much more overhead in maintaining those `.feature` files. If something in my background changes I have to manually update multiple files to keep them aligned.

Is there a way to share the textual background between multiple SpecFlow feature files?

Comment: How many steps are you copying and pasting between feature files?

Comment: @GregBurghardt if I want to be really descriptive? Around 5 to 10, and some using a table with multiple entries. That's one of the reasons I would like to write them out in each feature, opposed to a generic "Given the setup is done", because they are a relevant part and prerequisite of the feature.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question. I just can't give you an answer without more information about the features.